# Cats Example with nativescript secure storage do not update frontend

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

while playing around with the cats listview example from Raymond Camden
(thanks so much
[1]: https://nativescript.org/blog/client-side-storage-in-nativescript-applications/),
I try to store the data with the nativescript secure storage plugin.

In the cats.vue file I will show my code:

```
<template>
        <Page class="page">
            <ActionBar title="cats" class="action-bar" color="#ffbb00" />
            
                <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                
                    <ListView for="cat in cats">
                        <v-template>
                            <Label :text="cat.name"></Label>
                        </v-template>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button @tap="addCat" text="Add Cat"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            
        </Page>
    </template>

    <script>
    const appSettings = require("application-settings");
    var SecureStorage = require("nativescript-secure-storage").SecureStorage;
    var secs = new SecureStorage();
    
    var cats= [];

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function randomName() {
        var initialParts = ["Fluffy","Scruffy","King","Queen","Emperor","Lord","Hairy","Smelly","Most Exalted Knight","Crazy","Silly","Dumb","Brave","Sir","Fatty"];
        var lastParts = ["Saam","Smoe","Elvira","Jacob","Lynn","Fufflepants the III","Squarehead","Redshirt","Titan","Kitten Zombie","Dumpster Fire","Butterfly Wings","Unicorn Rider"];
        return initialParts[getRandomInt(0, initialParts.length - 1)] + ' ' + lastParts[getRandomInt(0, lastParts.length - 1)];
    }

    function getCats() {
        return secs.getSync({
            key: "foo"
        });
    }   


    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                cats: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.cats = getCats();
        },
        methods: {
            addCat() {
                cats = [{ "name":randomName()}, ...cats];
                
                var success = secs.setSync({
                    key: "foo",
                    value: cats
                });
                
                this.cats = getCats();
                
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

The problem is, I do not see any cats on the app screen, when I add a cat.

When I use the original code with the CouchDB, it updates the cats.
What should I change?

Also when the app starts, there are no visible cats which should be stored in another
start of the app. How may I load the data from the securestorage to the screen when the app starts?

May you please explain the changes, so that I can understand it?

Do you have good link with an explanation of nativescript-vue update the data synchronization to the screen?

Best regards and thank you very much for your help

Juergen

Comment: do you have the same "empty list on the second load " problem with CouchDB?

Comment: I tried the couchdb version again and there is no second load problem. That means on restart, the cats,which are added before, will be listed.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.

You should not use var as it is a global.

Remove the var cats= [], leave it only in data, not outside the export.

Further more move your other two functions to the methods within the exported object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robertino,
with following code there are 2 problems less:

```
<script>
const appSettings = require("application-settings");
var SecureStorage = require("nativescript-secure-storage").SecureStorage;
var secs = new SecureStorage();

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cats: []
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.cats = this.getCats();
    },
    methods: {
        addCat() {
            this.cats = [{ "name":this.randomName()},...this.cats ];
            //console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:" + cats);
            var success = secs.setSync({
                key: "foo",
                value: this.cats
            });
            
            this.cats = this.getCats();
            console.log(`after get:${this.cats}`);
        },
        getCats() {
            return secs.getSync({
                key: "foo"
            });
        },  
        getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        },
        randomName() {
            var initialParts = ["Fluffy","Scruffy","King","Queen","Emperor","Lord","Hairy","Smelly","Most Exalted Knight","Crazy","Silly","Dumb","Brave","Sir","Fatty"];
            var lastParts = ["Saam","Smoe","Elvira","Jacob","Lynn","Fufflepants the III","Squarehead","Redshirt","Titan","Kitten Zombie","Dumpster Fire","Butterfly Wings","Unicorn Rider"];
            return initialParts[this.getRandomInt(0, initialParts.length - 1)] + ' ' + lastParts[this.getRandomInt(0, lastParts.length - 1)];
        }
    }
};
```

I see a nice console.log in the method addcat() after the getcat method.
The cat data will be in the array after an add. And, when I restart, the cats stayed in the database.
The only problem now is, no cats where listed in the frontend.
Neither when adding nor when starting the app.
The data will not be shown in the frontend.
Any ideas?

Regards Juergen

Comment: SecureStorage sets the key value as string and this is how you see it in your console.log. To store objects you need to json.stringify them and when retrieving use json.parse to transform them back to object.

Comment: I tried like this getCats() {
                return JSON.parse(secs.get({
                    key: "foo"
                })); 
            }   and get the error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Try this: 
`secs.get({
  key: "foo"
}).then(
  function(value) {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  }
);`

Comment: Thanks again Robertino, now I have a problem at the addCats method: addCat() {
                this.cats = [{ name:this.randomName() }, ...this.cats]; error message is this.cats is not iterable. I don't understand, when should I use this.cats or cats?

Comment: what are you trying to do? It is not clear, you can use array destructuring having the same array as source and target.

Comment: I'm not sure. What is the best technique, to handle data on the screen and save it with securestorage on the phone, and load it while start of the app back to the screen? Is it better to use two seperate arrays, or only one?

Comment: If you want to display the secureStorage results in the template when the component is created all that you need is to have in created `this.cats = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(this.getCats()))`

Comment: I have problems with the development environment, I get in touch.

Comment: The development environment is running again. I do not understand the binding between the template and the data, the methods in the script. Do you know a good explanation for this?

Comment: Add the code in my example to the created hook in your component. It means that when the component is created your cats object will be filled with the data from secureStorage.